# Restcomm RTP standalone usage

Tags: rtp, jain-sip, restcomm

I'm using *jain-sip* as standalone application. Everything works fine for my purposes.
I need to do some modification to my application - play audio file before terminating a call (something like PLAY_ANNOUNCEMENT).
It would be something like this:

```
    -->INVITE  
    <-- 200 OK  
    <-- Play Audio  
    <-- Terminate call with BYE or CANCEL (depends on dialog state).
```

Currently it works without "Play Audio" step.

So my question is: How to use RestComm RTP stack separately from the RestComm MedaiServer?

**Some update.**

After studying MediaServer sources found that there must be *RtpFactory* class:

> class="org.mobicents.media.server.impl.rtp.RtpFactory"

Found here [rtp-beans.xml](https://github.com/RestComm/mediaserver/blob/master/bootstrap/src/main/config/rtp-beans.xml)

But I can't find this class in the sources - [RTP source](https://github.com/RestComm/mediaserver/tree/master/io/rtp/src/main/java/org/mobicents/media/server/impl/rtp)

Any help?